# Convert matlab to c++, bsxfun

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, bsxfun

I am trying to convert my MATLAB code to C++, and I find that there is a problem in the following situation:

**MATLAB**

```
A = rand(1000,40000);
b = rand(1000,1);
tic;
ans = bsxfun(@ne,b,A);
toc
```

**c++**

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > A;
std::vector<int> b;
std::vector<int> ans(10000);

// initial A and b
const clock_t begin_time = clock();
for(int i = 0; i < 40000; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j){
        if(A[i][j] != b[j])
            ans[i]++;
    }
}
double run_time = static_cast<double>((clock() - begin_time)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

I find that C++ case is three times slower than MATLAB. I would like to ask if anyone know how to change the C++ code so that I can have a similar or the same performance as `bsxfun` does?

After I searched the web, I find two possible ways:

1. include libraries from Armadillo
2. include libraries from Octave

But the point is that I am not sure how to do it, I mean I don't know the detail of implementation.

Summary:

1. I would like to ask if anyone know how to change the C++ code so that I can have a similar or the same performance as `bsxfun` does?
2. Can someone provide some hints or steps or example so that I can learn how to include Armadillo or Octave to do this task.

---

### EDIT:

Thanks to @Peter, I compile with option `-O3` and then the problem is "solved", I mean the speed is same as MATLAB.

Comment: Are you including the initialisation of `A` and `b` in your timing?

Comment: Does it help if you replace the `if` with `ans[i] += A[j][i] != b[j];`? (No branch prediction failures)

Comment: Have you tried parallelization? Depending on your system you could use pthread for example. You then create 4 Threads each calculating a part of the problem. That should speed your calculation up by a factor of nearly 4 (also depending on your hardware).

Comment: @sftrabbit no I do not include that time

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I have try and it does not help

Comment: Replace the `if` as @KlasLindbäck said, or even better: `ans[i] = A[j][i]!= b[j]` (no addition required)

Comment: This is likely to be a memory bound problem, so multithreading may well not gain much - but as @Peter's answer suggests, being cache efficient is likely to be the way forward.

Comment: @sflee: the two codes are not computing the same thing! Not to mention that `ans` in the C++ version is of the wrong size (it should be `40000`). Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you meant to write `ans = sum(bsxfun(@ne,b,A));` in MATLAB (the SUM(.) call was missing)

Comment: I don't recommend using _std::vector<std::vector<int>>_ for numerical tasks. It's inefficient from many points of view, especially speed. Instead, you'd get much better performance using a dedicated linear algebra library, such as [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net). See for example the [Mat](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) class,  which stores elements contiguously in column-major order, like Fortran. Also, a lot of Armadillo functions are [similar](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) to Matlab functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- You're running your loops in the wrong order.  In C and C++, 2D arrays are stored row-major, meaning `A[j][i]` and `A[j][i+1]` are next to each other in memory.  (Think of it this way: `A[j]` is the first subscript operation, returning a reference to another vector, which you then subscript again with `[i]`).

Keeping data in cache for as many operations as possible is one of the keys to performance on a modern processor, which means you want to access neighboring elements when you can.  So switch the order of the loops:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j){
    for(int i = 0; i < 40000; ++i){
```

2- Compiler options matter greatly.  Be sure you're building in "Release" mode, or with optimization on.

3- It is common to store 2D arrays in C++ as a 1D array, doing the row/column indexing yourself with multiplies.  That is, `A` would be a vector of size 1000*40000, and `A[j][i]` would instead be `A[j*row_length + i]`.  This has the benefit of more contiguous memory (see point 1), less dynamic memory allocations, and better cache utilization.

Comment: #3 is wrong because you talk about arrays, which already *are* stored consecutively.  The vector of vectors in the question is a different matter entirely, where your advice is valid.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, your MATLAB code is missing a call to the `sum` function (otherwise the two codes are computing different things!). So it ought to be:

#### MATLAB

```
A = rand(1000,40000);
B = rand(1000,1);
tic
count = sum(bsxfun(@ne, A, B));
toc
```

On my machine I get:

```
Elapsed time is 0.036931 seconds.
```

Remember that the above statement is [vectorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28parallel_computing%29) (think SIMD parallelization). MATLAB might also automatically run this [multithreaded](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95958) if the size is large enough.

---

Here is [my version](http://ideone.com/q2OrRa) of the code in C++. I'm using simple classes to create a vector/matrix interface. Note that the underlying data is basically stored as a 1D array with [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order) similar to MATLAB.

#### C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>        // rand
#include <ctime>          // time
#include <sys/time.h>     // gettimeofday

class Timer
{
private:
    timeval t1, t2;
public:
    Timer() {}
    ~Timer() {}
    void start() { gettimeofday(&t1, NULL); }
    void stop() { gettimeofday(&t2, NULL); }
    double elapsedTime() { return (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec)*1000.0 + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec)/1000; }
};

template<typename T>
class Vector
{
private:
    T *data;
    const size_t num;
public:
    Vector(const size_t num) : num(num) { data = new T[num]; }
    ~Vector() { delete[] data; }
    inline T& operator() (const size_t i) { return data[i]; }
    inline const T& operator() (const size_t i) const { return data[i]; }
    size_t size() const { return num; }
};

template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T *data;
    const size_t nrows, ncols;
public:
    Matrix(const size_t nr, const size_t nc) : nrows(nr), ncols(nc) { data = new T[nrows * ncols]; }
    ~Matrix() { delete[] data; }
    inline T& operator() (const size_t r, const size_t c) { return data[c*nrows + r]; }
    inline const T& operator() (const size_t r, const size_t c) const { return data[c*nrows + r]; }
    size_t size1() const { return nrows; }
    size_t size2() const { return ncols; }
};

inline double rand_double(double min=0.0, double max=1.0)
{
    return (max - min) * (static_cast<double>(rand()) / RAND_MAX) + min;
}

int main() {
    // seed random number generator
    srand( static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)) );

    // intialize data
    const int m = 1000, n = 40000;
    Matrix<double> A(m,n);
    Vector<double> B(m);
    for(size_t i=0; i<A.size1(); i++) {
        B(i) = rand_double();
        for(size_t j=0; j<A.size2(); j++) {
            A(i,j) = rand_double();
        }
    }

    // measure timing
    Timer timer;
    timer.start();

    // in MATLAB: count = sum(bsxfun(@ne, A, B))
    Vector<double> count(n);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
        count(j) = 0.0;
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
            count(j) += (A(i,j) != B(i));
        }
    }

    timer.stop();

    // elapsed time in milliseconds
    std::cout << "Elapsed time is " << timer.elapsedTime() << " milliseconds." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
$ g++ -Wall -O3 test.cpp -o test
$ ./test
Elapsed time is 63 milliseconds.
```

If I compile and run it with OpenMP support enabled, I get:

```
$ g++ -Wall -O3 -fopenmp test.cpp -o test_omp
$ ./test_omp
Elapsed time is 16 milliseconds.
```

Not a bad improvement (almost x4 faster) just by adding a single line to the code (the `pargma omp` macro).

This last one beats the 37 ms I get in MATLAB (R2013b). The code was compiled using GCC 4.8.1 (MinGW-w64 running on Windows 8, Core i7 laptop).

---

If you really want to push the limits here for the C++ code, you'll have to add vectorization (SSE/AVX intrinsics) in addition to the multithreading achieved with OpenMP.

You might also want to consider using [GPGPU programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units) (CUDA, OpenCL). In MATLAB that's very easy to do:

```
AA = gpuArray(A);
BB = gpuArray(B);
CC = sum(bsxfun(@ne, AA, BB));
C = gather(CC);
```

`gpuArray(.)` will transfer the matrix to the GPU, after which all operations done on it are performed on the GPU device instead of the CPU. `gather(.)` will transfer the array back to the MATLAB workspace. However the problem here is largely memory-bound, so will not likely see any improvement (possibly even slower due to the overhead of the data transfer).